# Как кастомизировать текст в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Я новичок в JS\CSS\HTML. Написал код, и мне интересно как перенести `.block-2` допустим немного правее и как его кастомизировать при JavaScript.

```js
document.querySelector('.block-1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.block-2').innerHTML = 'loremispum\nloremispum';
})
```

```html
<div class="block-1">Купить</div>
<div class="block-2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы точно так же можете менять и задавать стили в js как и в css.

```
const elem = document.querySelector('.block-1')
```

`elem.style` – объект, которому соответствует то, что написано в атрибуте "style". Установка стиля elem.style.width="100px" работает так же, как наличие в атрибуте style строки width:100px.

Можно задать сразу несколько стилей одной строкой:

```
elem.style.cssText=`color: red !important;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
  `;
```

https://learn.javascript.ru/styles-and-classes